# Button content closes on click of next button

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, svg

I have two buttons which store tables, but I want the table to disappear on click of the second button and show the contents of the second button immediately after clicking it, rather than clicking it twice (first click hides the table from the previous button, next clicks opens table from the current button).I don't seem to know how to do that.

```js
function myFunction2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("displaytable");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="Button1" value="Button1" onClick="myFunction2()" />
<div id="displaytable" style="display:none">
  <table id="displaytable" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" border="3">
    <tr align="center">
      <td class="lbl">column1</td>
      <td class="lbl">column2</td>
      <td class="lbl">column3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td align="center">2</td>
      <td align="center">33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">4</td>
      <td align="center">5</td>
      <td align="center">6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<input type="button" id="Button2" value="Button1" onClick="myFunction2()" />
<div id="displaytable" style="display:none">
  <table id="displaytable" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" border="3">
    <tr align="center">
      <td class="lbl">column1</td>
      <td class="lbl">column2</td>
      <td class="lbl">column3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">36</td>
      <td align="center">45</td>
      <td align="center">33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">4</td>
      <td align="center">5</td>
      <td align="center">6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Ids should be unique, you used an id twice that will make you into trouble. Do something like this `id="displaytable_1"` and `id="displaytable_2"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to make the following updates:

- You cannot have elements with same id as you had with your button and divs. See the modifications, I renamed them as displaytable1 , 2 and so on.
- This code works even if you have multiple number  of buttons and its corresponding tables (10,20 or even 100). You don't have to make a seperate function for each button click and can run a loop, so when you click 1 button it will just open that table and close all the remaining tables in this line:

`for(i=1;i<=2;++i)` where '2' is the last table id index and likewise the maximum id of a table as displaytable2.

- The function gets a parameter which is an integer, depending on the serial id of the button or the corresponding table that is, 1 for the first, 2 for the second like demonstrated in the code.
- You might want to get all your buttons lined up together separately and the tables separately like shown below so when a button is clicked, the rest of the buttons don't go down below the table.

```js
function myFunction2(index) {
  var x = document.getElementById("displaytable"+index);
  for(i=1;i<=3;++i) //3 because we have 3 tables
  {
    if(index==i){
      x.style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById("displaytable"+i).style.display = "none";
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="Button1" value="Button1" onClick="myFunction2('1')" />
<input type="button" id="Button2" value="Button2" onClick="myFunction2('2')" />
<input type="button" id="Button3" value="Button3" onClick="myFunction2('3')" />
<div id="displaytable1" style="display:none">

  <table width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" border="3">
    <tr align="center">
      <td class="lbl">column1</td>
      <td class="lbl">column2</td>
      <td class="lbl">column3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td align="center">2</td>
      <td align="center">33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">4</td>
      <td align="center">5</td>
      <td align="center">6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>


<div id="displaytable2" style="display:none">
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" border="3">
    <tr align="center">
      <td class="lbl">column2</td>
      <td class="lbl">column4</td>
      <td class="lbl">column5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">36</td>
      <td align="center">45</td>
      <td align="center">33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">4</td>
      <td align="center">5</td>
      <td align="center">6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>


<div id="displaytable3" style="display:none">
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" border="3">
    <tr align="center">
      <td class="lbl">column11</td>
      <td class="lbl">column23</td>
      <td class="lbl">column2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">3</td>
      <td align="center">45</td>
      <td align="center">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">4</td>
      <td align="center">00</td>
      <td align="center">6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used an id in multiple times that is completely wrong, you most use classes instead or use unique ids. BTW you used an id 4th times and this will puts you in trouble when you are using JS and its not standard coding.
**JS**:

```
function myFunction1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("displaytable1");
    var y = document.getElementById("displaytable2");
    y.style.display = "none";

    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("displaytable2");
    var y = document.getElementById("displaytable1");
    y.style.display = "none";
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="button" id="Button1" value="Button1" onClick="myFunction1()"/>
<div id="displaytable1" style="display:none">
    <table id="displaytable1_1" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" border="3">
        <tr align="center">
            <td class="lbl">column1</td>
            <td class="lbl">column2</td>
            <td class="lbl">column3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">1</td>
            <td align="center">2</td>
            <td align="center">33</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">4</td>
            <td align="center">5</td>
            <td align="center">6</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<input type="button" id="Button2" value="Button1" onClick="myFunction2()"/>
<div id="displaytable2" style="display:none">
    <table id="displaytable2_2" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" border="3">
      <tr align="center">
          <td class="lbl">column1</td>
          <td class="lbl">column2</td>
          <td class="lbl">column3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td align="center">36</td>
          <td align="center">45</td>
          <td align="center">33</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td align="center">4</td>
          <td align="center">5</td>
          <td align="center">6</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

P.S: i made changes as follow:
convert id from `displaytable` to `displaytable1` for first `div` element and 
convert id from `displaytable` to `displaytable2` for secound `div` that contains second table, and gave each table an unique ids. Regards

Comment: This won't work with the what the OP has required. They have mentioned that with the click of 1 button, the rest of the tables should disappear but with your code they won't. They'll just stack up until and unless you close them seperately. Button1 won't close the displaytable2

Comment: Removed it since you made an effort to fix it.

Comment: @Highdef I am realy glad for having such nice and reasonable in this community, +1 for your answer as it is